# Subset in user-defined functions

Tags: r, subset, user-defined-functions

I'm new to the programming world, and so I do appoligise in advance if it's really simple want I'm asking.
So I need to create a UDF that will make subset's from my data frame based on the levels of one variable from that data frame.

```
 x<-c("a","b","c","a","b","c")
 y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
 df<-data.frame(x,y)
 df
```

```
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
4 a 4
5 b 5
6 c 6
```

My idea was that I could store the levels into a vector, list or character, and so I would take every level and create the subset.

```
listlvls <- lapply(df, function(x) levels(df$x)) # levels as a list
chrlvl<-levels(df$x) # levels as a character enumeration
dflvl<-data.frame(chrlvl) # levels as a dataframe`
```

And I tried this with all three of the above being y but none worked:

```
subsetloop<-function(df,x,y){
  for(i in y){
    df[i]<-subset(df,df$x=='i')
  }
}
```

I want to save the subset into a new data frame with the levels name. For exemple for subset a :

```
adf

  x y
1 a 1
2 a 4
```

Comment: You don't need a loop `split(df, df$x)` if it is to create three datasets.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` to split into a `list` of subset of data.framess

```
lst1 <- split(df, df$x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple:

```
levels <- unique(as.character(df$x))
newDF <- list()
for(i in 1:length(levels))
{
  newDF[[i]] <- subset(df,df$x==levels[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `group_split` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_split(x)
```